# How to use linq in a session to filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, session

I am struggling to create session to filter data as excel, reason for my approach i think this filter well data according whats on the database. My logic somehow uses join and it does not bring data correctly instead its duplicating the record. While if i query on the database i get responce correctly. How can i use sessions in linq c# to achieve correctly? If i filter data by YEAR(2021) Week(53) must give me back according what is available using session this what i want to achieve here.

```
public IList GetExtractionViewModels()    
{    
var db = new ProductionManagementEntities();    
var scheduleList = (from p in db.ProductionDays    
from m in db.Models    
from mx in db.Models    
from mt in db.Models    
from mv in db.Models    
from wk in db.Models    
join w in db.Weeks on p.WeekId equals w.WeekId    
orderby w.Year descending, m.Name descending, p.ProductionDate descending, w.WeekNum descending, mt.Name descending, mx.Name descending, mv.Name descending    
where (mx.InActive == true)    
where (mt.InActive == false)    
where(m.InActive == false)    
where(mv.InActive == false)    
where(w.WeekNum < 53)    
where (mt.Name == "VW270")    
where(mx.Name == "VW250")    
where(m.Name == "VW270PA")    
where(mv.Name == "VW250/2PA")    
select new ExtractionViewModel    
{    
Year = w.Year,    
Day = p.ProductionDate,    
Week = w.WeekNum,    
VW270 = mt.Name,    
VW270PA = m.Name,    
VW250 = mx.Name,    
VW2502PA = mv.Name    
}).ToList();    
return scheduleList;    
}  
  
// model      
public class ExtractionViewModel      
{      
    public string Year { get; set; }     
    public int Week { get; set; }    
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]      
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }    
    public string VW250 { get; set; }    
    public string VW270 { get; set; }     
    public string VW2502PA { get; set; }      
    public int VW270PA { get; set; }      
}  
  
// Sql for Model    
SELECT TOP (1000) [ModelId]    
      ,[Name]    
      ,[Code]    
      ,[CreatedDate]    
      ,[CreatedBy]    
      ,[ModifiedDate]    
      ,[ModifiedBy]    
      ,[InActive]    
  FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[Model]    
  where Name = 'VW240'    
  order by InActive  
  
//Week table    
    
SELECT TOP (1000) [WeekId]    
      ,[WeekNum]    
      ,[Year]    
      ,[CreatedDate]    
      ,[CreatedBy]    
      ,[ModifiedDate]    
      ,[ModifiedBy]    
      ,[InActive]    
  FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[Week]    
    
// ProductionDate    
SELECT TOP (1000) [ProductionDayId]    
      ,[WeekId]    
      ,[ProductionDate]    
      ,[DayOfWeek]    
      ,[CreatedDate]    
      ,[CreatedBy]    
      ,[ModifiedDate]    
      ,[ModifiedBy]    
      ,[InActive]    
  FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[ProductionDay]  
  
  
// Controller for exporting data  
public ActionResult List()    
        {    
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];    
            var Client = new MongoClient(constr);    
            var db = Client.GetDatabase("ProductionManagementEntities");    
    
            var collection = db.GetCollection<ExactionViewModel>("ExtractionViewModel").Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();    
    
            return View(collection);    
        }  
  
public void DownloadExcel()    
       {    
           string constr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];    
           var Client = new MongoClient(constr);    
           var db = Client.GetDatabase("Employee");    
    
           var collection = db.GetCollection<ExactionViewModel>("ExtractionViewModel").Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();    
               
    
           ExcelPackage Ep = new ExcelPackage();    
           ExcelWorksheet Sheet = Ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report");    
           Sheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Year";    
           Sheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Week";    
           Sheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "Day";    
           Sheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "VW250";    
           Sheet.Cells["E1"].Value = "VW270";    
           int row = 2;    
           foreach (var item in collection)    
           {    
                   
               Sheet.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", row)].Value = item.Year;    
               Sheet.Cells[string.Format("B{0}", row)].Value = item.Week;    
               Sheet.Cells[string.Format("C{0}", row)].Value = item.Day;    
               Sheet.Cells[string.Format("D{0}", row)].Value = item.VW250;    
               Sheet.Cells[string.Format("E{0}", row)].Value = item.VW270;    
               row++;    
           }    
               
    
           Sheet.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();    
           Response.Clear();    
           Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";    
           Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment: filename=" + "Report.xlsx");    
           Response.BinaryWrite(Ep.GetAsByteArray());    
           Response.End();    
       }
```

Comment: What does "session" mean in this context?

Comment: Session in a way can hold all those table records, so each time records gets filters retrieve data back exactly as it is